# Is it safe to use 'project.getTasks().findByPath()' to get a task registered by a sibling project?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a multi-module gradle project.

```
ParentProject
 |--ProjectA
 |--ProjectB
```

`ProjectA` registers a `taskA` in its `build.gradle` file.

```
tasks.register("taskA", TaskA)
```

I'm writing a custom plugin. That plugin is applied to `ProjectB` and it registers `taskB` which depends on the output `OutA` of `:ProjectA:taskA`.

Here is how I pass the `OutA` of `:ProjectA:taskA` to the `taskB`.

```
TaskA taskAInstance = (TaskA) project.getTasks().findByPath(":ProjectA:taskA");

TaskProvider<TaskB> taskBProvider =
        project.getTasks()
                .register(
                        "taskB",
                        TaskB.class,
                        task -> {
                            task.dependsOn(":projectA:taskA");
                            task.getInputY()
                                    .value(
                                            taskAInstance
                                                    .getOutA()
                                                    .get());
```

Q1) Is it safe to do this?

My doubt is, can `taskAInstance` be null in some cases based on the configuration order? For eg. if gradle configures `ProjectB` before `ProjectA`.

Q2) If it can be null, can I do a null check for `taskAInstance` at my plugin, and register `:ProjectA:taskA` if its null?

Q3) If yes, how?

Q4) Are there any better ways of doing this?